# Receive XML with special characters

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to parse XML with characters like **é**, **ñ** I'm using UTF8 as encoding..

I have already tried change the encode to **NSISOLatin1StringEncoding** but It doesn't work

The code is:

```
   -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
//NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//  NSLog(theXML);
[theXML release];
if( xmlParser )
{
    [xmlParser release];
}
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
[xmlParser parse];
if (connection) {
    [connection release];
    }
  }


 -(void)callWS {
  NSString *url = @"theUrlHere";
  NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   if (conn) {
      webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
   }
```

When I receive the xml response...The results with special characters appears wrong...

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
  {
   if(!soapResults)
{
 ....//the soapResults here appears wrong when It has special chars...

  }
```

Example: **Caperuçú** appears **çú** , **Indianópolis** appears **ópolis**

Comment: Please elaborate on “appears wrong”.

Comment: Are you sure the encoding is UTF8?

Comment: Example: **Caperuçú** appears **çú** , **Indianópolis** appears **ópolis**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation of the `parser:foundCharacters:` delegate method:

> The parser object may send the delegate several
>   parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an
>   element. Because string may be only part of the total character
>   content for the current element, you should append it to the current
>   accumulation of characters until the element changes.

I assume that your code does not accumulate the characters and just uses the result of the *last* `parser:foundCharacters:` call.

The following sample program shows this effect with your input strings:

```
-(void)parse
{
    NSString *xmlString = @"<a><b>Indianópolis</b><c>Caperuçú</c></a>";
    NSData *xmlData = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"didStartElement: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"didEndElement: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"foundCharacters: %@", string);
}
```

*Output:*

```
didStartElement: a
didStartElement: b
foundCharacters: Indian
foundCharacters: ópolis
didEndElement: b
didStartElement: c
foundCharacters: Caperu
foundCharacters: çú
didEndElement: c
didEndElement: a
```

So this is not an encoding issue.

Comment: but if the character found has not special character, the character come in a unique time..How do I to come when has special char too?

Comment: @illDev: The usual solution is to create a `NSMutableString` (e.g. in `didStartElement`), and append to this string in `foundCharacters`. Then you have the complete string in `didEndElement`.

Comment: I have created a appendString  if(!soapResults)
    soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   NSLog(@"stringFound:%@", string);
    [soapResults appendString:string];
}

but the second elementName get the first+second element name value...the third gets first+second+third ....

Comment: @illDev: You have to reset the string to `nil` in `didStartElement`.

Comment: -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    
    soapResults = nil;
    
} ?

Comment: @illDev: It depends at bit how complex your XML is, but yes that is what I meant.

Comment: Usually, when your string is cropped due to special chars, it's because you're not using a ```NSMutableString*```. You must append the remaining chars till ```didEndElement```