# Simple stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString help issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I want to replace some "ilegal" characters from a string to another "legal" characters, I have this code:

```
- (NSString *) quitarTildes:(NSString *)aStr
{
    NSString *aux = aStr;
    NSString *invalid = @"áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ";
    NSString *valid = @"aeiouAEIOUnN";
    for (int i = 0; i < [invalid length]; i++)
        [aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[invalid characterAtIndex:i]] 
                                       withString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[valid characterAtIndex:i]]];
    NSLog(@"%@",aux);
    return aux;
}
```

And all ilegal character still there...

```
NSString *test = @"Hólá, Ésto es una prueba.";
test = [self quitarTildes: test];
```

NSLog, response:

```
2013-04-04 08:58:52.896 GeoRuta_v1[1960:907] Hólá, Ésto es una prueba.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One. You're using the wrong format specifier for `characterAtIndex:`. That method returns `unichar` and **not** `char` (for obvious reasons). You have to use `%C` (capital C).

Two. You're returning the original string, and not replacing its characters.

```
NSMutableString *tmp = [aStr mutableCopy];
// ...
[tmp replaceOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [invalid characterAtIndex:i]] 
                     withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [valid characterAtIndex:i]]];
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer, It really works my idea was in a good way, I forgot about `%c` and `%C` and I thought that method worked with a normal `NSString`, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: Returns a new string
>   in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are
>   replaced by another given string.
>
> -(NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement

So:

```
aux = [aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[invalid characterAtIndex:i]] 
                                       withString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[valid characterAtIndex:i]]];
```

Comment: When I did that, the xcode gave me an error about returning values, I interpreted that method doesn't return, just modify by reference. My bad, I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps simpler solution to achieve your goal:

```
NSString *test = @"Hólá, Ésto es una prueba. - áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ";
test = [test stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch locale:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

*Output:*

```
Hola, Esto es una prueba. - aeiouAEIOUnN
```

Comment: @rokimoki: Yes - why don't you try it? (It may depend on what you call "illegal". It should work for all characters with diacritical marks.)

Comment: It's illegal for the NSXMLParser, but I figured out that this will not work for what I'm doing, because I want to put the accents again, my convert mode will á to ::-a-:: (for example), and then I will convert ::-a-:: to á, why I'm doing this? because the NSXMLParser won't parse diacritical marks, I searched lot of answers and anyone worked, just want my method running. Thanks.

Comment: @rokimoki: Your question was about replacing "á" by "a", now you want to replace "á" by "::-a-::" (and back)? - Also I am quite sure that NSXMLParser works with diacritical marks if you do it correctly (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/14201660/1187415).

Comment: At least for me not, if I have, `<name>Solumática</name>` it will parse `<name>Solum</name><name>ática</name>`, the diacritical mark is there but I have two tags and my app will not work. @MartinR, but I have solved it with my question, I think it's a good solution, those XML will not be so long so... it will code-encode in less than 1 second. =)

Comment: @rokimoki: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14201660/1187415. The `foundCharacters` delegate method can be called *multiple times* for the same element, and you have to *concatenate* the strings. That is normal and documented behaviour. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14987201/1187415.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think that behaviour ruined my life for weeks.

Comment: @rokimoki: You are welcome. (You can upvote http://stackoverflow.com/a/14201660/1187415 if it was helpful to you :-)

Comment: I upvoted your answer here because was helpful, but I'm still using my method because I consider an easiest solution (even if easiest or not, for me it's valid), and I really appreciate all help you give me.